# Checking for authentication on every page after initial OAuth authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, google-oauth

I am building a RESTful web service, and using Google OAuth to grant the user access initially. For subsequent pages, how do I check that the user has been authorized? For example, in case of signing in with a username and password, we use session.getParameter() on every page to check that username and password are not null and thus ensure that the user has signed in, so that the page cannot be viewed just by typing the URL on the browser. How do I do something similar after the initial authentication has been done using OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using OAuth 2, you shouldn’t be using username and password. Normally, the idea is that OAuth gives the user an access token which is sent with each HTTP request; the access token is good for an hour or so.

Helpful reading at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2 and especially https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login